# remove fivestar rating from $print['content'] in print module

Tags: 7, rating

I installed the [print module](https://www.drupal.org/project/print). But in the print view, the [fivestar](https://www.drupal.org/project/fivestar) rating of the node is shown. How can I remove it?
It seems to be in `$print['content']`. Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- go to your content type manage display page and enable the custom display for the print view mode: http://prntscr.com/e0k5d6
- go to newly enabled print custom display and hide your fivestar field: http://prntscr.com/e0k633